# What is the zero locus of an ideal in a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Given an ideal $I$ of the polynomial ring $R = K[X_1, ..., X_n],$ we know that $I$ is finitely generated. I want to understand the zero locus of the ideal $I$. What one usually does is simply finding the zero locus of the system of polynomials belonging to the generators $(f_1,...f_d)$ of $I$. Let $p\in R.$ Then, $pf_1\in I$ but the zeros of $p$ must not coincide with the zeros of any of the polynomials $f_1,...,f_d.$ Very probably my statement is wrong, but I do not see how to realize that it is wrong. In particular since $p$ can be any polynomial in $R.$ I will appreciate a comment. Thanks.

Comment: The zeros are the common zeros of $f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n$, not the zeros of just an individual $f_i$.

Comment: The set of the points that annihilate *all* the generators of $I$ turns out to be the set of the points that annihilate *all* the polynomials in $I$. In fact, showing the two inclusions is barely a matter of algebra.